# archive&unarchive object

Tags: android, iphone

I have met a problem that I want to unarchive an object in Android, but the object was archived by iPhone. That means, the object is processed by the function:`[NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject]`, and I received the object in Android device, I need to do unarchive the object, but I have not find the way to do unachive in android using java. Need you help, thanks..

Answer (score 0):

You couldn't do that.
You should user xml or json to exchange data.

Comment: No way to implement function[NSKeyedUnarchiver unarchiveObjectWithData] in android? Or can I decode the content of archive object, I have found that archivedDataWithRootObject function use string "root" as the encode key to encode the serialization content, Can I decode the serialization content, It's actually a xml file.

Comment: It's not the standard xml file.

Comment: Yes, I know, but at first, we did not think about android device, the application was only run in iphone, now we must have compatibility with iphone and android, so we must solve this problem, I mean we must know internal of object serialization in iphone with function [NSKeyedArchiver archivedDataWithRootObject].